# swift push notifications and App Store

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

my swift 2 app is now ready for push notifications.
via my webspace and php i can send push notifications to the devices.

but at the moment only via sandbox url and in development mode.
My App is now ready for the App Store.

What i have to done, to send push notification in production mode?

At the moment, my Member Center looks like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is this all ok or is there anything missing?
And what is the push notification URL (not sandbox url => ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195​)

Thanks :)

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: You have to create new `Provisioning Profile` for production and make the `.pem` file as you created for the development purpose.
Production Url: `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195​`

Comment: i have an Provisioning Profil for production. i added the screen into post 1

Comment: and i created the pem file. if i use not the new pem file and the production url - can i send push notifications, before the app is in the app store (for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Production and Development push notification certificates are different, the push tokens received from Apple are different as well. So make sure the production server is using the Production certificate and sending to the production push token of the device.